How to show pull progress when using Go code to pull containerd image
I am using the following Golang code to pull containerd image.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/containerd/containerd"
    "github.com/containerd/containerd/namespaces"
)

func main() {
    // create connection to containerd
    client, err := containerd.New("/run/containerd/containerd.sock")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    // use k8s.io namespace
    ctx := namespaces.WithNamespace(context.Background(), "k8s.io")
    
    // pull image
    image, err := client.Pull(ctx, "docker.io/library/openjdk:17", containerd.WithPullUnpack)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf(" Pulled image: %s", image.Name())
}

The code worked well and silently pulled the image for me.
The question is, can I show the progress (e.g print BytesPulled/BytesTotal on console) during the pull? Any idea will be appreciated.

Tools like ctr and nerdctl typically query the content store to get the progress. Here's the implementation on how nerdctl does it: Link

Use github.com/schollz/progressbar/v3 to show progress like below:

The code that I tried:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "github.com/schollz/progressbar/v3"
)

func main() {
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := pullImage(cli, "openjdk:8"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Java 8 image has been successfully pulled.")
}

func pullImage(cli *client.Client, imageName string) error {
    out, err := cli.ImagePull(context.Background(), imageName, types.ImagePullOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer out.Close()

    bar := progressbar.DefaultBytes(-1, "Pulling image")
    _, err = io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, bar), out)
    return err
}

